# comments hooks on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, hooks, conditional-tags

First, this is what I want to achieve:

I want to add a comments hook on a CPT which is asking users to be registered and logged in to be able to post a comment. And after the user is logged in to display two custom fields before the comment field.

My discussion settings are not set to **Users must be registered and logged in to comment ** because on my default blog posts I don't want to force users to register in order to comment.

Here is what I've did till now :

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {

 if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {

  // these are the custom fields which I want to display before the comment field 
    $fields['first'] = '<p class="comment-form-first"><label for="first">' . 
                     __( 'HTML5' ) . 
                     '</label>' . 
                     '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true).'" /></p>';


    $fields['second'] = '<p class="comment-form-second"><label for="second">' . 
                       __( 'FLASH' ) . 
                       '</label>' .
                      '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'disagree', true).'" /></p>';

    return $fields;


}

else {

         return $fields;
}


} 
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

I've looked through the CODEX, and I found this `comment_form_must_log_in_after`  but this is not helping me because I need first to add a hook which is asking user to log in.

I've looked also into mytheme/comments.php here is a snippet:

```
  <div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h3 class="comments-title">

            <?php
                printf( _n('%d comment', '%d comments', get_comments_number(), 'outbox' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) );
            ?>
        </h3>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'outbox_comment' ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through? If so, show navigation ?>
        <nav role="navigation" id="comment-nav-below" class="site-navigation comment-navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-previous"><i class="icon-left-open-1"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo get_previous_comments_link( __( 'Older Comments', 'outbox' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php echo get_next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments', 'outbox' ) ); ?>&nbsp;<i class="icon-right-open-1"></i></div>
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below .site-navigation .comment-navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php
        // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
        if ( ! comments_open() && '0' != get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'outbox' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>
```

This is the 'must_log_in' :

```
        'must_log_in'          => '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
```

Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is simply not to display the comment field if the current user isn't logged in, using [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

For example, inside your comments template:

```
<?php comment_form( $args ); ?>
```

Just wrap that in a conditional:

```
<?php
// Don't output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in
if ( 'debate' != get_post_type() || is_user_logged_in() ) {
    comment_form( $args );
}
?>
```

### Edit

Just put it into the template directly:

```
<?php
// If CPT and not logged in, display a message:
if ( 'debate' == get_post_type() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) ) ) . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm looking trough the comments-template.php and I can't find anything similar with `<?php comment_form( $args ); ?>`, I've updated also my code with a snippet from the comments-template.  I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: Well then, how is your Theme outputting the comments form?

Comment: I've edited my question with the snippet containing the output

Comment: The very last line of your `comments.php`: `<?php comment_form(); ?>`

Comment: this is working, but I would like the to display default message from this  `'must_log_in'` $args. I've posted the code in my question

Comment: It this possible with this method ?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: It works now, but it's ok if I put it inside the comments template ? I'm saying this because I want to have the output inside the comments div

Comment: You can put it wherever you want to put it...